# Get Data from WKNavigationResponse in swift

Tags: swift, webview

This is my simplified code that I have so far:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    if whatever {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        guard let url = navigationResponse.response.url else { return }
        if let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileData], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

}
```

I'm doing this to download and share PDFs, etc.

This code works but the problem is that the attachment is downloaded twice, first by the webview and then by the Data() object which can lead to long delays. Is there a way to get a Data() object from WKNavigationResponse or maybe to fish out the data from the webview or it's cache? Or maybe to call UIActivityController() with some other parameters? Im thinking something like these (they don't work):

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [navigationResponse], applicationActivities: nil)
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [navigationResponse.response], applicationActivities: nil)
```